# Using xpath to query XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I am using xpath for the first time to query an xml document for a value and return the corresponding name value. I have been reading numerous different sources on the topic but I can't seem to get it to output correctly. Here is my `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <name>Genesis</name>
    <abrv>GEN</abrv>
    <title>The First Book of Moses</title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Exodus</name>
    <abrv>EXO</abrv>
    <title>The Second Book of Moses</title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Leviticus</name>
    <abrv>LEV</abrv>
    <title>The Third Book of Moses</title>
  </book>
</books>
```

Here is my `PHP`/`HTML`:

```
<?php $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/";
$bookID = 'GEN';
$xml = simplexml_load_file( $root . 'assets/xml/books.xml' ) or die( "No Page Data Found" );
$bookName = $xml->xpath( '//book[abrv="'.$bookID.'"]/name' );
?>
<article id="verseOfDay">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>verse of the day</h2>
    <h6><?php echo $bookName; ?></h6> // Line 19
    <p></p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Finally, here is the notice that I am receiving:

> NOTICE: ARRAY TO STRING CONVERSION IN /HOME/#####/MYWEBSITE.COM/ASSETS/INCLUDES/VERSEOFTHEDAY.PHP ON LINE 19
>   ARRAY

What am I doing wrong? In this example I am expecting it to output Genesis in the  tag.

Comment: Firstly, this is not an error, it is a notice. Secondly, you should give us what the output is and what the output should be, as the PHP can easily disregard notices. You have to give us also where is this `array to string conversion` as it is unclear which line is 19.

Comment: Take a look [at this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp). When you apply your xpath, it returns an array but you echo it in your HTML, causing a conversion from array to string.

Comment: `echo $bookName[0];` or foreach with that array if in real task you will get more than one result

Comment: @Martin My apologies. I have edited my question to include that information.

Comment: @Casper I began with that website. I don't have much experience with arrays so it's been confusing tonight trying to understand it.

Comment: @splash58 I tried that too and got a message along the lines of undefined something or other. I will try it again in the morning and let you know what it says.

Comment: @Angeliss44 I've run your code on my server and get the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SimpleXML [`xpath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) function returns an array of results, which will be empty if no result is found. So you need to check for that, and if you get a result, it will be at `$bookName[0]`. Something like this will work:

```
$bookNames = $xml->xpath( '//book[abrv="'.$bookID.'"]/name' );
$bookName = empty($bookNames) ? 'Not Found' : $bookNames[0];
?>
<article id="verseOfDay">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>verse of the day</h2>
    <h6><?php echo $bookName; ?></h6>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</article>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kOTRl)

Comment: This works beautifully! I think when I had tried using $bookName[0] before, my xpath query was different--something along the lines of "/books/book[abrv=$bookID]/name. Being 1am as I was working on this and posted this question I made the age old mistake of changing more than one thing at a time when trying to fix it. Thank you for the help as well as the explanation.